# Get drop down selected value from row in datatables when trigger button

Tags: javascript, datatables, datatables-1.10

I've included the sample in [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9p1L9g81/3/).

My question is, how to get the row drop down selected value when trigger the "click" button at the same row.

This is my HTML:

```
<table id="table1">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Item</th>
        <th>UOM</th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Item 1</td>
        <td>
            <select>
                <option></option>
                <option>BAG</option>
                <option>UNIT</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <button type="button" class="add">Click</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Item 1</td>
        <td>
            <select>
                <option></option>
                <option>BAG</option>
                <option>UNIT</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <button type="button" class="add">Click</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

My JavaScript:

```
oTable = $("#table1").dataTable({
    "fnDrawCallback": function(oSetting){
        $(".add").click(function(){
            var data = oTable.row($(this).parents('tr') ).data();
            console.log(data);
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

I would use [`rowCallback`](http://datatables.net/reference/option/rowCallback) to define a callback that gets executed when row is drawn.

Then you can query value of `<select>` element by `$('select', row).val()` as shown below:

```
'rowCallback': function(row, data, index){
    $('.add', row).click(function(){
        console.log($('select', row).val());
    });
}
```

**DEMO**

See [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9p1L9g81/6/) for code and demonstration.

Comment: @Michael, sorry I've meant to recommend `rowCallback` instead of `createdRow`, it's better suited for this. I have updated my answer and demo.

Comment: got it. thx! My ultimate goal is to get the values and $.post to server.